# Add ckan license to uploaded file from java

Tags: java, ckan

I have created a java client that uploads files to a ckan installation. I would like to add a license on the file. From the ckan docs i see that there is a json file on the ckan installation with all the available licences, but i am not sure how i can use that on my client
example taken from ckan [docs](http://docs.ckan.org/en/943-writing-extensions-tutorial/configuration.html#licenses-group-url)

```
licenses_group_url = file:///path/to/my/local/json-list-of-licenses.json
licenses_group_url = http://licenses.opendefinition.org/licenses/groups/od.json
```

part of my client programm is

```
ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(file, ContentType.TEXT_HTML);
HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
    .addPart("file", cbFile)
    .addPart("key", new StringBody(uploadFileName+date,ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
    .addPart("package_id",new StringBody("test2",ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
    .addPart("url",new StringBody(HOST+"/files/"+date+"/test.txt",ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
    .addPart("upload",cbFile)
    .addPart("comment",new StringBody("comments",ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
    .addPart("notes", new StringBody("notes",ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
    .addPart("author",new StringBody("AuthorName",ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
    .addPart("author_email",new StringBody("AuthorEmail",ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
    .addPart("title",new StringBody("title",ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
    .addPart("description",new StringBody("file Desc"+date,ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
    .build();
```

**Update**
After Odis hint i realised that I was wrong all along (aparently).
It turns out that the license of the file is automatically set to the license of the Dataset. I was uploading a file to a dataset with out a license so my file had no license. When i used this
`.addPart("license_id", new StringBody("CC-BY-4.0",ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))`
I was still getting no license on my file. When i changed the licence of my Dataset, no matter if i used that command or not, or even if used it with some other license Id, i was still getting the same license of the DataSet.

That makes no sence to me to be honest. Cant i have a Dataset with some license and some of my files use different licenses? Could someone confirm that please?

Comment: In CKAN the license is a field of the dataset, so you can't have a dataset where resources have different licences. In such cases, you would have to create a separate dataset.

Comment: @Odi ok, thanks for the clarification. it seems that i was looking for a solution to a non existing problem, since my code had nothing to do with it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you referred to is the [`license_group_file`](http://docs.ckan.org/en/943-writing-extensions-tutorial/configuration.html#licenses-group-url).

If you look at one of the entries, they look like that:

```js
{
    status: "active",
    maintainer: "Creative Commons",
    od_conformance: "approved",
    family: "",
    osd_conformance: "not reviewed",
    domain_data: true,
    title: "Creative Commons Attribution 4.0",
    is_okd_compliant: true,
    domain_content: true,
    url: "https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/",
    is_osi_compliant: "not reviewed",
    domain_software: false,
    id: "CC-BY-4.0"
}
```

As you can see there is a `id` field. This is what you can use when you create a dataset. Just pass the value (in the example above `CC-BY-4.0`) of the license in a field called `license_id` ([see the docs](http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.2/api.html#ckan.logic.action.create.package_create) for all the available fields)

Comment: for some reason the responce i get is showing the license `"license_id": "CC0-1.0"` but on the ckan site it still states `License not specified`. The code i used is `.addPart("license_id", new StringBody("CC0-1.0",ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))`